# RepositoryRestController is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I do not speak English very well Please understand.

It may not help, but I'll let you know my address.
[git](https://github.com/gongul/Repo.git)

RepositoryRestController is not working.
`@BasePathAwareController`, `@RepositoryRestController` Neither one of them works.
If mapping is used in the class area, no other repo can be used.
It worked with the same source a day ago.

Development environment
java 1.8
spring 4.3.8
spring data mongo 1.10.3
spring data rest 2.6.10
spring hateoas 0.23.0
mongo driver 3.0.2

controller

```
@RepositoryRestController
//@BasePathAwareController
//@RequestMapping(value = "")
public class ArticleController {

@Resource(name="articleCustomRepo")
private ArticleCustomRepository cRepo;

@Resource(name="articleService")
private ArticleService 

    @RequestMapping(value="/articles/{idx}/comments",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/hal+json")
    public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<List<CommentResource>> getComment(@PathVariable("idx") int idx) {

        List<CommentResource> list = cRepo.data(idx);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(list,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/articles",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/hal+json")
    public HttpEntity<ArticleResource> postArticle(@RequestBody Map<String,Object> map) {

            ArticleResource article = service.postArticle(map);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(article, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value><!--  -->classpath*:config/spring/context-config.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>


    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/v1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

context-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="horizon">
    </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

SpringConfig.java

```
package horizon.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpringDataWebSupport;
import org.springframework.hateoas.config.EnableEntityLinks;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableEntityLinks
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class SpringConfig {

}
```

Help me figure out how to fix it.

Comment: A couple of quick questions: (1) when you say "it does not work", what do you mean? What is the behaviour you are getting and what did you expect instead. (2) Can you remember what you changed since it was working a day ago?

Comment: (1) Mapping does not work.. (Override repository method on the controller
) (2) When I saw the record, nothing changed.

Comment: @dave  Did you understand me?

Comment: I think I understand. Unfortunately there's not enough info for me to help you :(

Comment: I'll show you my git address. [git](https://github.com/gongul/Repo.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It seems that you have a call loop between slf4j and log4j try to remove log4j dependencies from you pom.xml and check your tomcat logs
- create custom dispatcher servlet

  ```
  public class RestDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {
   public RestDispatcherServlet() {
    configure();
    }

  public RestDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext 
      webApplicationContext) {
    super(webApplicationContext);
    configure();
  }
  private void configure() {
  setContextClass(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class);
  setContextConfigLocation(
  RestMvcConfiguration.class.getName());
   }
  ```

  }
- update your web.xml dispatcher servlet
- create rest mvc app config

  ```
    @ComponentScan("horizon.board.controller")
    public class RestMvcConfiguration extends 
      RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
     }
  ```

Comment: What do I do if I want to use the log4j?

Comment: remove slf4j-log4j12 dependency

Comment: um... I removed the log4j from my pom, but I can't.

Comment: oh.. sry I was wrong.
um.. It does not work the same after deletion. RepositoryRestController is not woking

Comment: RepositoryRestController is not woking um.. class mapping  log Mapped "{[/articles/{idx}/comments],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json]} But method mapping doesn't produce that log.

Comment: RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet load the default RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration in which default scan package is in org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc package causes your custom RepositoryRestController not loaded, so create you own custom dispatcher servlet by extending RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet and pass a custom class that extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration

Comment: Can I get an example?

Comment: (1).Do I have to delete the RestDispatcherServlet from my web.xml?
(2). "update your web.xml dispatcher servlet" what's mean
(3). RestDispatcherServlet , RestMvcConfiguration Do I have to put the annotation in the class?

Comment: oh.. thank sir. you The problem is solved. but /articles/{idx}/comments List<CommentResource> In the result, the link does not come out as a _link, but comes out as a link. The format is not application / hal + json

Comment: happy to see your config works, could please share the complete error log for this new pb